# Rails - Cant get http_accept_language gem to work in my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm internationalizing my app and I've installed the http_accept_language gem on my system I've placed config.gem 'http_accept_language' into my environment.rb file but every time I try to run this code in my controller

request.user_preferred_languages

it complains of no method error.

There are no other instructions on the readme on github... am I missing something?

**EDIT - Problem solved.**

after a good nights sleep I came back and realised I hadnt restarted the server. I hate it when that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to reset the server (how embarassing).

Answer (score 0):

Did you:

```
sudo gem install http_accept_language
```

on your machine? What is the out put of:

```
gem list
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. It was in my gemlist. The problem was I forgot to reset the server (how embarassing).